# building yaml C++ giving problems

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

Though I copied the files from the yaml-cpp website, I am getting the following errors:

```
2>c:\git_sandbox\sandbox\templatematching\templatematchingframework\prj.thirdparty\yaml-cpp\src\stream.h(9): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'yaml-cpp/noncopyable.h': No such file or directory
2>  scantag.cpp
2>c:\git_sandbox\sandbox\templatematching\templatematchingframework\prj.thirdparty\yaml-cpp\src\ptr_vector.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'yaml-cpp/noncopyable.h': No such file or directory
```

Why can't windows find these files?

Comment: Well, does the file actually exist? Is the directory containing `yaml-cpp` in the compiler's include path? What compiler are you using? How are you invoking it?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio and after using their CMakeListsFiles.txt from yaml website to configure and generate the solution, I just build the solution from Visual Studio. No, the directory containing yaml-cpp is not in the compiler's include path, but CMake already should be handling that I thought.

Comment: Thanks Cameron actually including the yaml-cpp in the include path did the trick.